# Ant replaceregexp removing "\"

Tags: ant

While replacing a value **replaceregexp** task removing backslash ("\"). Below is the code sample.

```
 <replaceregexp
      match="${search.expression}"
      replace="${replace.expression}"
      flags="mg">
      <fileset dir="${file.directory}" includes="${file.search}" />
 </replaceregexp>
```

The input to the task is:

```
 [echo] Search expression -- ^.*name="SqlServerConnectionString".*$
 [echo] Replace expression -- <add name="SqlServerConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\MSSQLSERVER2016;Initial Catalog=DBName;user id=User;password=PWD" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Below is the replaced value:

```
<add name="SqlServerConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhosMSSQLSERVER2016;Initial Catalog=DBName;user id=User;password=PWD" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Please notice the difference between `localhost\MSSQLSERVER2016` and `localhosMSSQLSERVER2016`

I need to replace the input string as it is. Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to *double* escape back slashes in this situation, due to the way Ant's Java-based code resolves strings. The problem should be fixed by simply changing your replacement string to:

```
<add name="SqlServerConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\\\\MSSQLSERVER2016;Initial Catalog=DBName;user id=User;password=PWD" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```